# Send PHP if statement through HTML form

Tags: php, html

Trying to allow the user of an admin control panel to run a PHP if statement from an HTML form.

Due to the control panel integrating with a 3rd party software, we only have 1 way to select the data - using PHP variables.

An example of the if statement that would be being sent via the form

```
$contact_details['Contacted'] == "Yes"
```

The user will have an interface that will fill an HTML input field with the full if statement e.g.

```
$contact_details['Contacted'] == "Yes" && $contact_details['Country'] == "UK"
```

However, when the form is posted, the if statement doesn't filter the results properly.

```
echo $_POST["ifstatement"]."<br>"; //Show statement run - Remove when if works
if($_POST["ifstatement"]){ echo "Contact ID: ". $contact_details['id'] ." - Contact location: ". $contact_details['Country'] ." - "." Contacted?: ".  $contact_details['Contacted']."<br>"
```

It displays the statement as it should be running, however, it does not run the the query.

Is there any way to get this to work, or will I have to do this another way?

Comment: Create a `$mIfStatement` var and set it as a string with the if statement that you like. Then change your if statement `if($_POST["ifstatement"] == $mIfStatment)`

Comment: How is that if statement posted? As a string? Then you need to run it through `eval()` for it to be parsed as PHP. _NOTE:_ Be _very_ careful when using `eval()`. It will execute _any_ command as PHP and is considered to be _very_ insecure. There are usually much safer ways of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Adding to @Magnus Eriksson's answer about the eval() method. You can check php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php or www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_eval.asp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your If-Statement is not being evaluated. You have to use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to evaluate it. Please don't just copy this example mindlessly:

```
<?php
$foo = '$result = ' . $_POST["ifstatement"] . ';';
eval($foo);
if ($result) {
    // ...
}
?>
```

But this is a really bad Code Smell and you are creating a huge [remote code execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) bug if you don't sanitize the input properly.

So you should reconsidering your approach, because there will be a better and more safe on.